# JavaScript Offline Detection - function not available

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I have some troubles understanding JavaScript.

When I am making an ajax request and the user has no connection to the main server, the Connection class will be called with the function notify.

So when I now open the page, disable my internet and click the button, which fires the request, I get the alert You have no internet connection anymore.

As well as good. But the function "backup" will not be called. I get an error like that: TypeError: this.backup is not a function.

So have I missed something? JavaScript is client side, so why can't I execute the function?

PS: When I am executing the function notify, when I have internet it works.

```
function Connection() {
  this.backup = function() {
    var data = [["Backup_Scenario"], ["123"]];
    var csv = this.createCSV(data);
    this.downloadCSV(csv);
  }

  this.notify = function() {
    alert("You have no internet connection anymore");
    this.backup();
  }

  this.createCSV = function(data) {
    var lineArray = [];
    data.forEach(function (infoArray, index) {
        var line = infoArray.join(",");
        lineArray.push(index == 0 ? "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + line : line);
    });
    var csvContent = lineArray.join("\n");
    return csvContent;
  }

  this.downloadCSV = function(csv) {
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csv);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "backup.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    link.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/d61cwhcq/ Tried "offlining" via DevTools and via OS. File still downloads without issues. Chrome 60, Windows 10.

Comment: It works for me too: https://jsfiddle.net/pb3bm9jd/

Comment: check `this` inside your `notify()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, 
the mistake was that I put the code directly as callback by an ajax request like that:

```
connection = new Connection();
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  error: connection.notify
});
```